# CustomRequiredvalidator did not get triggered

Tags: validation, jsf

I am confused because my custom required validation did not get triggered.
I got a class which creates my HtmlTextInput element programmatically and adds
the validator. Moreover I got my custom validator class. Console tells me that 
validators got bound to HtmlTextInput. Anyway after hitting 'save' 
CustomRequiredValidator did not get called! I am using JSF 2.x. Thanks in 
advance.

```
// programmatically built HtmlInput-element
if (freeText.isRequired()) {
    // Validator-Objekt
    System.out.println("CustomRequiredValidator bound.");
    final CustomRequiredValidator validator = (CustomRequiredValidator) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createValidator("CustomRequiredValidator");
    inputText.addValidator(validator);
}

// CustomValidator
@FacesValidator("CustomRequiredValidator")
public class CustomRequiredValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        System.out.println("RequiredValidator.validate ..."); ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Really strange: for example, if I let the field empty, or typed one space in it - validate() won't get called. If I type a value like '1234' in the field, validate() will get called?!

Comment: Please note that the cast on `CustomRequiredValidator` completely defeats the abstraction (i.e. the `Application#createValidator()` approach is completely pointless and you could as good just use `new CustomRequiredValidator()` here). Get rid of the cast and just declare it as `Validator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validators are only invoked if conversion has succeed. So if there's a converter, either explicitly registered or implicitly used (e.g. having an `Integer` bean property would trigger the JSF builtin `IntegerConverter`) and it threw a `ConverterException`, then the validator will never be triggered. You should however have noticed this converter exception in any of the associated `<h:message(s)>` component or the server logs.

If the converter is excluded from being suspect, then another possible cause is that JSF is configured to not validate empty fields by having the following context parameter in webapp's `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Other than that, well, running a debugger, starting with a breakpoint at [`UIInput#validate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.validate%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method should give insights.

Comment: In my web.xml there is no entry like javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS. In my console I am not able to see that a ConverterException got thrown. I have to find out, how I can debug the ProcessValidation phase. Currently I think if my System.out.println did not get reached, a breakpoint won't be reached as well. Offtopic: thanks BalusC, I think it is great that you are trying to support people here!

Comment: Uh, I pointed out the exact class/method to put the breakpoint on: `UIInput#validate()`. Have you tried it? I did not say to put the breakpoint on your custom validator.

Comment: Damn, I can't get it done to set a breakpoint in UIInput class. I just have the class-files here. I will try to get it done, Eclipse offers me an option to attack some source. I will try to solve this.

Comment: Mojarra source is available at http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html. Just download the source ZIP file and point to exactly that file in Eclipse's "Attach source". I'd expect you to already have done that... Debugging without source is not funny :) Make sure that you download exactly the same JSF source version as JSF binaries actually being used.

Comment: I think I need Apache MyFaces, unfortunately I need Version 2.0.7, I am just able to find 2.0.18, see https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/myfaces/core/myfaces-api/ . As it seems I got a problem and I guess next time I will try to store all related sources somewhere on my machine.

Comment: You're looking in the "snapshots" repo... As per [MyFaces download page](http://myfaces.apache.org/download.html), you can find older releases in the archive at http://archive.apache.org/dist/myfaces/, more specifically 2.0.7 [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/myfaces/source/myfaces-core-assembly-2.0.7-src.zip)

Comment: Great advice! I am able to use my debugger now. I started in UIInput validate(). After following further invocations I recognized, that in UIComponentBase.processValidators() my CustomValidator should be in the collection. Anyway I am not able to inspect the objects in the list and grab relevant information for me, i. e. invoke a method to get the name of the object. Currently I just get some object reference addresses on the heap - so no information for me. Usually I am using the eclipse-expression-view for debugging to detect relevant property values. Thanks for further help if possible.

Comment: Did you from `UIInput#validate()` step into `UIInput#validateValue()` (line 582) and subsequently `_ComponentUtils#callValidators()` (line 437)?